# In Meteor Js how do I add a referral code from query string to user profile?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm using the accounts-entry package in a Meteor application. I want to be able to give partners to our application the ability to refer users to us with a link, eg: `ourawesomeapp.com?partnerId=1234`. When a user comes from a partner I want to be able to store that in the [users collection](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_users) under a `partnerId` field to pay commissions when users spend money with us. I'm currently trying to use this: (note this Accounts.onCreateUser() method runs on the server only)

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user){
  user.partnerId = partnerId from the query string here...;
  return user;
});
```

The spot I'm getting stuck at is getting the `partnerId` from the query string to the server to be able to use it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the recommended routing package for Meteor, [iron-router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router), you can access the query string like this:

```
// given the url: "/?partnerId=1234"
Router.route('/', function () {
  var partnerId = this.params.query.partnerId;
});
```

If [the query string isn't available on the server](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/632), an option is to make the `partnerId` a URL path instead of query string:

```
Router.route('/partner/:_id', function () {
  var partnerId = this.params._id;
}, {where: 'server'});
```

More in the [iron-router guide](http://eventedmind.github.io/iron-router/).

Comment: As I understand it Accounts.onCreateUser() can only run on the server, which the route parameters aren't available. Am I missing something?